# How to remove single line comments in php (eg "// remove this comment")?

Tags: php, regex, comments

I want to remove all single line comments (eg `//comments`) from my code using regular expression.

By now I'm using: `preg_replace('/\/\/(.*)/','',$html);` but it also removes strings like `http://example.com`.

Comment: What are you using `ob_start` then? Just open the file, do your replacement and save it?

Comment: The regex would need to ignore `://` but not `//`.

Comment: It would really surprise me, if you could do this reliably with regular expressions on something else than just trivial code.

Comment: I am developing a compression plugin in wordpress.I want to minify all the codes on loading. So can't remove //comments manually

Comment: If you want to do it right, look at PHP's built-in tokenizer: http://php.net/manual/de/book.tokenizer.php Edit: Just saw nickf's answer. It's basically the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this reliably. There is no guarantee that `//` at any position in a file indicates a comment in PHP context. It might very well be contained in a string for example.

It's only possible to approach this with a few concessions. For example if it is sufficient if it catches `// comments` on a single line, then this would be an option with less false positives:

```
$source = preg_replace('#^\s*//.+$#m', "", $source);
```

The real solution would be utilize a language parser, but that's obviously overkill. So try with adding some heuristics to avoid removing wrong occourences.

Comment: It will fail with the heredoc and nowdoc string syntax :-S

Comment: something like this: window.location.href = '//' + hostname + url; will become window.location.href =

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps a better method would be to use the PHP engine itself, perhaps by using [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php). That function will tokenise a PHP script, so you can view it exactly as PHP views it, and hence remove or replace comments.

Doing this with a regex alone would be at best a nightmare, and most likely not possible at all.

Comment: Actually, that's the only useful way to go. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
 preg_replace('/.*?:?(\/\/.*)/','',$html);
```

You could try something like this, but I'm sure you can safe use regular expressions to account for all possible edge cases.

However as mentioned above using a tokenizer is a better and more reliable method of doing this. In fact there is an example of how to remove comments from a PHP file in the comments on php.net man pages, [see here](http://php.net/manual/function.php-strip-whitespace.php#91065). This could server as a good start point, but I recommended testing this for yourself. Code in the comments on php.net man pages can often be a bit dodgy.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get any other alternative, might I suggest. Although performance wise it's not the best approach.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $source);
$lines = array_map(
  function($line) {
    return preg_replace("@\s*//.*$@", '', $line);
  },
  $lines
);
$source = implode("\n", $lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to minify your PHP code, why not use [php_strip_whitespace( )](http://www.php.net/php-strip-whitespace)?

Answer (score 0):

```
function stripPhpComments($code)
{
    $tokens = token_get_all($code);
    $strippedCode = '';

    while($token = array_shift($tokens)) {        
        if((is_array($token) && token_name($token[0]) !== 'T_COMMENT') 
            || !is_array($token)) 
        {
            $strippedCode .= is_array($token) ? $token[1] : $token;
        }
    }
    return $strippedCode;        
}
```